# What is the `[` command?

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

I have seen both in Cygwin and in Linux the `[` command under `/bin`. Whenever I run it I get an error saying: `missing ]`.

I never understood what this command does, I just one day found it wanted to find out what it does (and whether it is useful or not)

**NOTE:** I would have checked the `man` entry, for an answer, but sadly, there is no entry in it for `[`

Comment: What is the command?

Comment: @TiagoƇ. The command is called `[`

Comment: In bash, it is re-implemented as a built-in command. At a bash prompt type `help [`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [`test`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test) command.

For example, find out if `/etc/passwd` exists or not:

```
[ -f /etc/passwd ] && echo "Yes" || echo "No"
```

Regularly you write it as follows:

```
if test -f /etc/passwd
then
  echo "Yes"
else
  echo "No"
fi
Read
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever seen/noticed if conditions in shell scripts? They are of the form:
`[ -e $FILE ]`

In those cases, the condition checking functionality is usually built-into the shell interpreting those scripts, usually bash or sh-aliased-bash.

The binaries that you see serve the same purpose, but are present so condition checks can be used in shells **without** such functionality built-in.

Answer (score 2):

The [ square bracket is another way to call the `test` command.

Refer to [test's Man page](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html) for further info :)